Is there any ONE book which covers full physics from a 1st year level way till graduate level?
Guys I'm looking for a single textbook in physics which takes you from a 1st year level of university till advanced level like graduate level. I have a basic knowledge of Grade 11th and 12th physics and looking up for more advanced level. And I'm financially weak and can't afford expensive multiple books.

I am almost 100% certain that such a book does not exist.  The standard undergraduate physics curriculum is too broad to be contained in a single volume.

That said, if you are looking for a low-cost textbook to cover first-year university physics, OpenStax has a free one that's not bad.

The Feynman Lectures are available online

Have a look in Physics LibreTexts but you won't get a single book covering everything in a B.Sc. level course.

This question (v2) seems too broad topic-wise for a res. recom q.

Many colleges also publish lectures/work online (MIT, notably). If you’re interested in a particular course you might look up the work for it and read through.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine I have been surprised lately at the level of depth in some of the Physics LibreTexts site...even going so far as to cover basic QFT and Perturbation QM. It seems like a great way for academics to contribute to a large repository of knowledge.
